# Integrating Derivatives of Inverse Trigonometric Functions When They Are in Similar, Yet Different Forms

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, trigonometric-integrals

I am familiar with the derivatives of the three trigonometric functions:

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \arcsin(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \arccos(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \arctan(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$

And I understand how to find the antiderivatives/integrate them IF they are in the same form as above. However, I often encounter them in similar, yet different forms:

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$

$\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}$

$\dfrac{1}{3+x^2}$

In this form, I am unable to use any method to integrate them -- not even substitution (since there will always be an $x$ left over).

If I encounter these forms, how do I take the antiderivative/integrate them? If there is a method, what is the reasoning behind it (why does it work)?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do the first example, which should be illustrative. The key is to factor out the constant inside the square root. Write
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{9 - x^2}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{1 - (\tfrac{x}{3})^2}}.$$
Now you can integrate the right-hand side with the $u$-substitution $u = \tfrac{x}{3}$.

Comment: Oh, wow! Such a simple, yet effective method. Thanks again, Ethan! :)